# PostgreSQL/PostGIS: ST_distance query should only return "nearest" result

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I would like to query the distance for every point (id) in table A to every polgygon (id) in table B. For the distance calculation I am using ST_Distance. However, ST_Distance returns (obviously) the distance to every polygon. But I only need the "closest" result for each point. So far, I tried the following query which returns the correct result but (of course) for exactly one point.

```
SELECT polygons.id, points.id, ST_Distance(points.geom, polygons.geom) 
FROM table_A AS points, table_B AS polygons 
ORDER BY st_distance ASC LIMIT 1
```

The result should be something like this:

```
polygon_id | point_id | min(distance)
-------------------------------------
1234       |   876    |   54.32
...        |   ...    |    ...
-------------------------------------
```

Do you have any hints? Thank you very much.

**UPDATE 1**

```
WITH CTE AS
       (SELECT polygons.id as poly_id, points.id as point_id, 
        ST_Distance(points.geom, polygons.geom) as thedistance , 
        row_number() OVER
              (PARTITION BY points.id ORDER BY ST_Distance(points.geom, polygons.geom)) 
    FROM 
        table_A AS points
    INNER JOIN table_B AS polygons
    ON ST_DWithin(points.geom, polygons.geom, 100)) SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE row_number = 1
```

After running the above query (3h 24m) there was empty result returned. However, there should a result. Is it possible that there is a problem with parentheses?

**UPDATE 2**

The SRID is 4326 (WGS84) and the polygons are OSM building polygons and the points arbitrary points in the same city.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [window](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html) function and a [CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/queries-with.html). Something like this:

```
WITH CTE AS
   (select polygons.id as poly_id, points.id as point_id, 
    ST_Distance(points.geom, polygons.geom) as thedistance , 
    row_number() OVER
          (PARTITION BY points.id ORDER by ST_Distance(points.geom, polygons.geom) ) 
FROM 
 table_A AS points, table_B AS polygons )
 select poly_id, point_id, thedistance from CTE where row_number = 1
```

However, this might be slow if you have lots of points. You can speed it up by using [st_dwithin](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html) in a join that uses an index, if you know roughly how far apart your points are from your polygons. Just set the distance parameter so you catch every point:

```
WITH CTE AS
   (select polygons.id as poly_id, points.id as point_id, 
    ST_Distance(points.geom, polygons.geom) as thedistance , 
    row_number() OVER
          (PARTITION BY points.id ORDER by ST_Distance(points.geom, polygons.geom) ) 
FROM 
    table_A AS points
INNER JOINT table_B AS polygons
ON st_Dwithin(points.geom, polygons.geom, 5000 )) -- assumes you have a metres projection, limit to 5KM
select * from CTE where row_number = 1
```

Be sure you have GIST indexes on both your GEOM columns

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I am currently running your proposed query and I expecting it to be finished by tomorrow. I will let you know.

Comment: The query finished after 3.5 hours, however without results. I had to modify your query a little bit. I added a closing parentheses before the final select statement see Update 1 above.

Comment: Yes - looks like a typo with the bracket, apologies. Will fix it. Can you post some sample records? Also, what SRID are you using? It could be that your distance is too restrictive and you are not finding anything...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am using 4326 WGS84. Which is in degrees I guess. I tried it once with one single point id and I think DWithin showed the correct result. Maybe I can exclude the inner JOIN?

**EDIT** sample data is difficult to provide. Basically, I am looking at OSM building polygons and the distance to arbitrary points (some city).

Comment: The point of the st_dwithin is that it uses an index so should be much faster. However, that won't make much sense with an SRID in degrees. Try the first query instead...

Comment: Thank you for your help. The first query is even faster. But in pgadmin, there is still no output but no error. At least one row should be returned?

Comment: Pgadmin notifies, that the query was successful but affected rows "-1". If there was no results, then at least the table headers should be returned?